# Specify a collection to tf checkout and tf checkin, when working with multiple workspaces

Tags: tfs

When working with **multiple** workspaces, executing either of the following commands:

- `tf checkout "$/path/to/file.cs"`
- `tf checkin "$/path/to/file.cs"`

... results in the following error message:

```
Unable to determine the workspace. You may be able to correct this by   
running 'tf workspaces /collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl'.
```

One solution is to `cd` into the required collection's mapped folder.
For example, if `$` of the above server path is mapped to the local path `C:\my-root-folder`, then the following works:

```
cd C:\my-root-folder
tf checkout "$/path/to/file.cs"
```

**My question:**
Is it possible to make it work without `cd`, by somehow specifying the collection before calling `tf checkout` (or `tf checkin`)?

For example, if `tf workspaces` outputs something like:

```
Collection: https://my-first-domain/some-collection
Workspace      Owner     Computer       Comment
-------------- --------- -------------- ------------
MY_SERVER_NAME  MY_NAME  MY_SERVER_NAME

Collection: https://my-second-domain/some-other-collection
Workspace      Owner     Computer       Comment
-------------- --------- -------------- ------------
MY_SERVER_NAME  MY_NAME  MY_SERVER_NAME
```

Then executing the following **doesn't** work:

```
tf workspaces /collection:https://my-first-domain/some-collection
tf checkout "$/path/to/file.cs"
```

Can we change something to make it work?

Comment: I don't think it's possible :/

Answer (score 0):

> Specify a collection to tf checkout and tf checkin, when working with multiple workspaces

I agree with Shayki Abramczyk. I am afraid there is no such way to achieve tf checkout without mapped folder.

The reason is that the server needs to know the mapping between the server paths and the local paths.

The way that TFS was intended to be used.